# Custom Event in GWT widget is not working

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin7

I am working on application in Vaadin for my classes.
I have to draw some map on the screen so I'm using gwt-graphics lib.
I have also some servlet which is waiting for requests.
When some specific request will come view of the map should be changed.
It lead me to prepare custom event:

```
// class NewModulePositionHandler
package com.example.locator;

import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler;

public interface NewModulePositionHandler extends EventHandler {
    void onNewModulePosition(NewModulePositionEvent event);
}
```

Below implementation of my custom event:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent;

public class NewModulePositionEvent extends GwtEvent<NewModulePositionHandler> {
    private static final Type<NewModulePositionHandler> TYPE = new Type<NewModulePositionHandler>();
    private final String m_Color;

    public NewModulePositionEvent(String color) {
        m_Color = color;
    }

    public static Type<NewModulePositionHandler> getType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return m_Color;
    }

    @Override
    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<NewModulePositionHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(NewModulePositionHandler handler) {
        handler.onNewModulePosition(this);
    }

}
```

And it's time for implementation of my custom widget:

a) MyComp.java

```
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent;

public class NewModulePositionEvent extends GwtEvent<NewModulePositionHandler> {
    private static final Type<NewModulePositionHandler> TYPE = new Type<NewModulePositionHandler>();
    private final String m_Color;

    public NewModulePositionEvent(String color) {
        m_Color = color;
    }

    public static Type<NewModulePositionHandler> getType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return m_Color;
    }

    @Override
    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<NewModulePositionHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(NewModulePositionHandler handler) {
        handler.onNewModulePosition(this);
    }

}
```

b) MyCompClientRpc.java

```
import com.vaadin.shared.communication.ClientRpc;

public interface MyCompClientRpc extends ClientRpc {

    // TODO example API
    public void alert(String message);
    public void changeColor(String color);
}
```

c) MyCompConnector.java

```
package com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.vaadin.client.ui.AbstractComponentConnector;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.Connect;
import com.example.locator.MyComp;
import com.example.locator.NewModulePositionEvent;
import com.example.locator.NewModulePositionHandler;
import com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp.MyCompWidget;
import com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp.MyCompServerRpc;
import com.vaadin.client.communication.RpcProxy;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.vaadin.shared.MouseEventDetails;
import com.vaadin.client.MouseEventDetailsBuilder;
import com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp.MyCompClientRpc;
import com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp.MyCompState;
import com.vaadin.client.communication.StateChangeEvent;

@Connect(MyComp.class)
public class MyCompConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {
MyCompServerRpc rpc = RpcProxy
        .create(MyCompServerRpc.class, this);

public MyCompConnector() {
    registerRpc(MyCompClientRpc.class, new MyCompClientRpc() {
        public void alert(String message) {
            // TODO Do something useful
            Window.alert(message);
        }
        public void changeColor(String color) {
            getWidget().InitMap(color);         
        }
    });

    // TODO ServerRpc usage example, do something useful instead
    getWidget().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            final MouseEventDetails mouseDetails = MouseEventDetailsBuilder
                .buildMouseEventDetails(event.getNativeEvent(),
                            getWidget().getElement());
            rpc.clicked(mouseDetails);
        }
    });


    getWidget().addNewModulePositionHandler(new NewModulePositionHandler() {

        public void onNewModulePosition(NewModulePositionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rpc.newModulePosition(event.getColor());
        }

    });

}

@Override
protected Widget createWidget() {
    return GWT.create(MyCompWidget.class);
}

@Override
public MyCompWidget getWidget() {
    return (MyCompWidget) super.getWidget();
}

@Override
public MyCompState getState() {
    return (MyCompState) super.getState();
}

@Override
public void onStateChanged(StateChangeEvent stateChangeEvent) {
    super.onStateChanged(stateChangeEvent);

    // TODO do something useful
    final String color = getState().color;
    getWidget().InitMap(color);
}

}
```

d) MyCompServerRpc.java

```
package com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp;

import com.vaadin.shared.MouseEventDetails;
import com.vaadin.shared.communication.ServerRpc;

public interface MyCompServerRpc extends ServerRpc {

    // TODO example API
    public void clicked(MouseEventDetails mouseDetails);
    public void newModulePosition(String color);
}
```

e) MyCompState.java

```
package com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp;

public class MyCompState extends com.vaadin.shared.AbstractComponentState {

    // TODO example state
    public String color = "#000000";

}
```

And finally implementation of the widget:

f) MyCompWidget.java

```
package com.example.locator.widgetset.client.mycomp;
import org.vaadin.gwtgraphics.client.DrawingArea;
import org.vaadin.gwtgraphics.client.Line;
import org.vaadin.gwtgraphics.client.shape.Circle;
import org.vaadin.gwtgraphics.client.shape.Rectangle;

import com.example.locator.HasNewModulePositionHandlers;
import com.example.locator.NewModulePositionEvent;
import com.example.locator.NewModulePositionHandler;
import com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.HashMap;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
import com.google.gwt.touch.client.Point;
import com.example.locator.Module;

// TODO extend any GWT Widget


public class MyCompWidget extends DrawingArea implements HasNewModulePositionHandlers {

    public static final String CLASSNAME = "mycomp";
    public static double m_AreaWidth = 64.355;
    public static double m_AreaHeight = 17.385;
    public static int m_PictureWidth;
    public static int m_PictureHeight;
    public static double m_AreaToMapRatio;
    public static double m_RouteWidth = 3.5;
    public static double m_MainRouteCoordinateY = 8.0828;
    public Circle circle;
    //public HashMap<Integer, Module> ModuleMap = new HashMap<Integer, Module>();

    public MyCompWidget(){
        super(640, 320);

        //ModuleMap.put(666, new Module(666, 30.0, 8.08, new Circle((int)TranslateCoordinate(30.0), (int)TranslateCoordinate(8.0), 7)));
        //ModuleMap.put(15, new Module(15, 27.0, 8.08, new Circle((int)TranslateCoordinate(30.0), (int)TranslateCoordinate(8.0), 7)));

        double xRatio = m_AreaWidth / 640;
        double yRatio = m_AreaHeight / 320;
        m_AreaToMapRatio = xRatio > yRatio ? xRatio : yRatio;

        InitMap("#919491");
        setStyleName(CLASSNAME);
    }

    public void InitMap(String color)
    {
        m_PictureWidth  = (int)TranslateCoordinate(m_AreaWidth);
        m_PictureHeight  = (int)TranslateCoordinate(m_AreaHeight);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, m_PictureWidth, m_PictureHeight);
        rectangle.setFillColor(color);
        add(rectangle);
        Point point1Beg = new Point(0.0, 8.0828);
        Point point1End = new Point(64.355, 8.0838);

        Point point2Beg = new Point(20.2825, 8.0828);
        Point point2End = new Point(20.2825, 17.385);

        Point point3Beg = new Point(59.325, 0.0);
        Point point3End = new Point(59.325, 8.0828);

        point1Beg = TranslatePoint(point1Beg);
        point1End = TranslatePoint(point1End);

        point2Beg = TranslatePoint(point2Beg);
        point2End = TranslatePoint(point2End);

        point3Beg = TranslatePoint(point3Beg);
        point3End = TranslatePoint(point3End);

        Line line1 = new Line((int)point1Beg.getX(), (int)point1Beg.getY(), (int)point1End.getX(), (int)point1End.getY());
        Line line2 = new Line((int)point2Beg.getX(), (int)point2Beg.getY(), (int)point2End.getX(), (int)point2End.getY());
        Line line3 = new Line((int)point3Beg.getX(), (int)point3Beg.getY(), (int)point3End.getX(), (int)point3End.getY());

        line1.setStrokeColor("#FFFFFF");
        line2.setStrokeColor("#FFFFFF");
        line3.setStrokeColor("#FFFFFF");

        line1.setStrokeWidth((int)TranslateCoordinate(m_RouteWidth));
        line2.setStrokeWidth((int)TranslateCoordinate(m_RouteWidth));
        line3.setStrokeWidth((int)TranslateCoordinate(m_RouteWidth));

        add(line1);
        add(line2);
        add(line3);

        DrawWall(TranslateCoordinate(10.0));
        DrawWall(TranslateCoordinate(20.0));
        DrawWall(TranslateCoordinate(30.0));
        DrawWall(TranslateCoordinate(40.0));
        DrawWall(TranslateCoordinate(50.0));
        DrawWall(TranslateCoordinate(60.0));

        DrawDoor(3.0, 3.0);
        DrawDoor(13.0, 3.0);
        DrawDoor(23.0, 3.0);
        DrawDoor(33.0, 3.0);
        DrawDoor(43.0, 3.0);
        DrawDoor(53.0, 3.0);
        circle = new Circle((int)TranslateCoordinate(25.0), (int)TranslateCoordinate(8.0), 15);
        add(circle);
    }

    public void DrawWall(double a_Place)
    {
        Line line = new Line((int)a_Place, 0, (int)a_Place, (int)TranslateCoordinate(m_AreaHeight));
        line.setStrokeColor("#FFFFFF");
        add(line);
    }

    public void DrawDoor(double a_Position, double a_Width)
    {
        double realDoorPositionY = m_MainRouteCoordinateY - (m_RouteWidth / 2);
        int doorPositionYTop = (int)TranslateCoordinate(realDoorPositionY) - 1;
        int doorPositionYBottom = (int)TranslateCoordinate(realDoorPositionY + m_RouteWidth) + 1;

        Line line = new Line((int)TranslateCoordinate(a_Position), doorPositionYTop, (int)TranslateCoordinate(a_Position) + (int)TranslateCoordinate(a_Width), doorPositionYTop);
        line.setStrokeColor("#000000");
        line.setStrokeWidth(2);
        add(line);
        Line line2 = new Line((int)TranslateCoordinate(a_Position), doorPositionYBottom, (int)TranslateCoordinate(a_Position) + (int)TranslateCoordinate(a_Width), doorPositionYBottom);
        line2.setStrokeColor("#000000");
        line2.setStrokeWidth(2);
        add(line2);
    }

    public Point TranslatePoint(Point a_Point)
    {
        Point translatedPoint = new Point(TranslateCoordinate(a_Point.getX()), TranslateCoordinate(a_Point.getY()));
        return translatedPoint;
    }

    public double TranslateCoordinate(double a_Coordinate)
    {
        return (a_Coordinate) / (m_AreaToMapRatio);
    }

    public void Move(int id) {
        //ModuleMap.get(id).GetCircle().setX(10 + circle.getX());
    }


       public HandlerRegistration addNewModulePositionHandler(
                NewModulePositionHandler handler) {
            return addHandler(handler, NewModulePositionEvent.TYPE);
        }

        private void someMethod() {
            fireEvent(new NewModulePositionEvent("#000000"));
        }
        public void emulateEvent() {
            someMethod();
        }
}
```

g) HasNewModulesPositionHandlers.java

```
package com.example.locator;

import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;

public interface HasNewModulePositionHandlers {
    // Attention! method returns HandlerRegistration, so that handler can be cancelled
    public HandlerRegistration addNewModulePositionHandler(
            NewModulePositionHandler handler);
}
```

If I compile the widgets set containing MyCompWidget and then run my application on glassfish I get the following message:

> Widgetset 'com.example.locator.widgetset.LocatorWidgetset' does not contain implementation for com.example.locator.MyComp. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.

If I cut

> ```
>   public void addNewModulePositionHandler(
>             NewModulePositionHandler handler) {
>         handlerManager.addHandler(NewModulePositionEvent.getType(), handler);
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     }
> ```

widget works properly (of course I have to comment out these lines from MyCompConnector as well):

```
    getWidget().addNewModulePositionHandler(new NewModulePositionHandler() {

        public void onNewModulePosition(NewModulePositionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rpc.newModulePosition(event.getColor());
        }

    });
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem? It seems that compilation of the widget failes but I can't find any information about that.
Please, help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation problem is very clear: GWT compiler cannot fins source code for a specified java class. You add source files to GWT compiler scope in two steps:

1. *.java files must be accessible through classpath (eclipse gwt compiler automatically includes all source folders to classpath)
2. You need to tell GWT that it should consider your packages during compilation

   - Create .gwt.xml file in PARENT package (relative to your source files) with the following content (if your package is pkg1.pkg2.pkg3, then you should in package pkg1.pkg2 create file "Pkg3.gwt.xml", pkg = "pkg3", by convention pkg3 is typically named "client")

> ```
> <module>
>     <source path="pkg3" />
> </module>
> ```

!!!Be careful with letter cases, By convention those are the correct names.

- Add to your widgetset.gwt.xml file "inherits" directive like that

> ```
> <inherits name="pkg1.pkg2.Pkg3" />
> ```

!!! Pay attention to letter cases (P is capital in Pkg3, after file name Pkg3.gwt.xml), .gwt.xml is omitted here

Then, first of all, Vaadin uses GWT with a certain twist. I would recommend browsing through custom widgetset samples. You may need to understand how to propagate events to and from Vaadin-specific components. Below I explain how GWT event are supposed to be implemented and used. I'm not an expert in Vaadin, especially in advanced topics such as customizing widgetsets.

So, speaking of GWT.

Basically, you need to understand only two things to make (non-DOM, also knows as bitless) events work in GWT.

1. Code support

   - Event class. NewModulePositionEvent in your case.
   - Event Handler interface. NewModulePositionHandler in your case.
   - Feature interface (optional but advised). HasNewModulePositionHandlers in your case.
2. Usage pattern

   - Basically, the component that is supposed to fire event should create relevant Event object and pass it to the fireEvent method. All the logic to invoke necessary habdler is provided by EventBus (internally)
   - If you need to provide API to fire events externally (such as click() method for a Button), it should be done by providing special methods (do not expose internal stuff how exactly event is fired)

DOM events are special in details how they are created (by browser) and dispatched (they need to be explicitly enabled). Anyway, all the browser events are already implemented in GWT out of the box.

So, typical implementations for the above items: For the sake of clarity, I provide excerpts from our production code.

1) Event class

```
public class QuestionClickEvent extends GwtEvent<QuestionClickHandler> {

    public QuestionClickEvent(SScript script, SQuestion question) {
        super();
        this.script = script;
        this.question = question;
    }

    public static final Type<QuestionClickHandler> TYPE = new Type<QuestionClickHandler>();

    // internal event state
    private final SScript script;
    private final SQuestion question;

    @Override
    public Type<QuestionClickHandler> getAssociatedType() {
         return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(QuestionClickHandler handler) {
        handler.onQuestionClicked(this);
    }


    // provide access to internal event state

    public SScript getScript() {
        return script;
    }

    public SQuestion getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
}
```

2) Handler interface

```
public interface QuestionClickHandler extends EventHandler {
    public void onQuestionClicked(QuestionClickEvent event);
}
```

3) Feature interface

```
public interface HasQuestionClickHandlers {
    // Attention! method returns HandlerRegistration, so that handler can be cancelled
    public HandlerRegistration addQuestionClickHandler(
            QuestionClickHandler handler);
}
```

4) Your widget/component

```
public class SummaryPanel extends Widget implements HasQuestionClickHandlers {
// blah-blah-blah

        // implement your handler registration method
    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addQuestionClickHandler(
            QuestionClickHandler handler) {
        return addHandler(handler, QuestionClickEvent.TYPE);
    }

// blah-blah-blah

    private someMethod() {
        // suddenly you realized that you need to to fire your event
        fireEvent(new QuestionClickEvent(script, question));
    }

// sample external API method

    public void emulateEvent() {
        someMethod();
    }
}
```

And finally usage example:

```
    SummaryPanel summary = new SummaryPanel();
    summary.addQuestionClickHandler(new QuestionClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onQuestionClicked(QuestionClickEvent event) {
            // your reaction goes here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have applied your hints to my code(I updated main post), but the widget is still not working. (It compiles successfully without my event).
Did I understand something wrong? Do you need more details to solve my problem?